# Tracking user behavior on the client, across pages

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, analytics, matomo

I'd like to be able to track user behavior on my site, using JavaScript, and display messages to the users accordingly. For example:

- A user visits my site for the first time
- A user does a number of actions on my site
- A user comes from specific region that is important to my business (this is optional)

I was using Google Analytics before, and recently switched to Piwik. I was hoping that Piwik would provide a JavaScript API for obtaining info about the current visitor, but it does not.

What other good libraries for tracking user behavior in the browser can you recommend?

Comment: You say you were using GA, were you using the event tracking feature as well?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a list...](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-web-analytics-packages-for-tracking-your-visitors/)

I have used [AWstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) pretty extensively. It's pretty standard. It's not very pretty, but it provides a lot of great analytics. When you combine it with [JAWstats](http://www.jawstats.com/), you get brains and beauty.

[Woopra](https://www.woopra.com/) looks like it's aimed right at the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use external services like http://www.intercom.io or http://mixpanel.com for this - both with JS API and back-end api's for many languages.

Have good experience with intercom so far, looking into mixpanel atm.

In intercom you segment your users and can direct messages to them by either email or inApp messages. E.g. *If user is from Norway AND user has sessions=1 THEN show greeting message in norwegian.*
You can add your own tags easily to target segments important to you.

After trying mixpanel briefly I'd say the biggest difference is that intercom is communication oriented whereas mixpanel is behaviour oriented.